# Getting the value of the checkbox value that has been changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-post, onchange

I have several checkboxes on my page that each correspond to different courses. When the user checks the checkbox I want to sent a POST request to the server to add details of their enrollment to the database.

I have the following jQuery to take note of the change:

```
$(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").change(function () {
        var fullURL = document.URL;
        var url = fullURL.split('userID=');
        var userID = url[1];

        var courseID =

        alert(userID + "and " + courseID);

        $.post('/Admin/EnrolUser/', postData, function (data) {

        });
    });
});
```

On my page there are several checkbox inputs, how can I retrieve the value of the selected checkbox that fired the event and set this to the var courseID variable.

Comment: var courseID = $(this).prop("checked") // $(this).val(); could help. have you setting id's to each checkbox?? if so then you can easily do this var courseID = $(this).attr("id");.. i hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Every jQuery function that deals with collections set's the value of `this` to be the current element.

So...

```
$("input:checkbox").on("change", function(){

   $(this).val(); //Element that fired event

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `change` function the variable `this` represents your checkbox.

```
    $("input:checkbox").change(function () {
    var fullURL = document.URL;


    var courseID = $(this).val();

    alert(courseID);

});
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/36cBf/1/)